# Can mean standard error be transformed and remain interpretable?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, standard-error, error-propagation

Suppose I collect a two random sample from separate populations

Sample 1 has:
$$
\bar{x}_1 = A \\
SE(\bar{x}_{1}) = C
$$

Sample 2 has:
$$
\bar{x}_2 = K \\
SE(\bar{x}_{2}) = N
$$

I am interested in the percent change between the two, so 
$$
\Delta{\bar{x}} = \frac{K-A}{A}
$$

Could I do something similar with the standard error where
$$
\Delta{SE}_{1} = \frac{(K+N) - (A+C)}{(A+C)} \\
\Delta{SE}_{2} = \frac{(K-N) - (A-C)}{(A-C)}
$$

or even

$$
\Delta{SE} = \frac{N - C}{C}
$$

There is no chance of having a zero in the denominator. I'm curious if it's still interpretable or if it's even possible to compute an error on the transformed $\bar{x}$ statistic. My gut feeling tells me this is wrong, but am being asked for work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard error of the mean-percent difference (MPD) is quickly found by applictaion of the $\delta$-method:

$f(x, y) = (y-x)/x$ so $\nabla f(x,y) = [y/x^2, 1/x]$.

If the two samples are independent,

$$\text{var}(MPD) = [K/A^2, 1/A]^T \left[ \begin{array}{cc}  C & 0 \\ 0 & N \\ \end{array} \right] [K/A^2, 1/A] $$

Doing the algebra for SE gives you the desired result.

Comment: What if the two samples are dependent? Say, a group of people's weight before and after and treatment?

Comment: @dylanjm estimate the covariance and replace the 0s in the $2 \times 2$ covariance matrix with that.

Comment: One last quick question, is there a way to compute confidence intervals instead of standard error doing something similar and accounting for dependence between observations?

Comment: Please try to avoid adding nontrivial additional questions (rather than just simple clarification) once the posted question has been answered. If you have a new substantive question post it (and where relevant link bank to earlier related questions)